# Magento2 installation "php bin/magento setup:install", "php bin/magento setup:upgrade" not working

Tags: installation, magento2, upgrade

Hope you are doing well.

I am trying to install magento2.4.4 on vmware ubuntu 20.04 system.
Current php version is 7.4.33, composer version is 2.5.5, ubuntu 20.04.

For installing I used below command.
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition=2.4.4 magento
(this works fine and the magento project downloaded)

for installing, after that I ran this command :
sudo php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://localhost/magento_test --db-host=localhost --db-name=magento_test --db-user=root --db-password=root --admin-firstname=admin --admin-lastname=admin --admin-email=admin@admin.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1

But it doesn't work and returns anything (even errors). I can't find the solution.

For checking further, I downloaded working magento project which was working correctly in other hosting server and try to run "php bin/magento setup:upgrade", it still doesn't work. The same issue like above.

I really can't find the solution.
How to resolve this? Please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.
Best regards.

I tried
php bin/magento setup:install
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

...
I was expecting this command working but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2.4.4 requirement php8, so just try install php8.1 and run command line install magento again (remember you need to go to magento root directory to run this command line)